# Branding resource settings ignored when user is logged in to DocuSign console

Tags: docusignapi

Today I uploaded custom resource files for a Brand in order to disable the Finish Later button.  I noticed something odd:  the settings in my uploaded resource file are honored when noone is logged in to the DocuSign console, and I no longer see the Finish Later button.

However, if I am logged in as either the admin or sender user for my account, then the resource settings are apparently ignored and the Finish Later button reappears.

Has anyone else observed this, and is there some way to get the resources to be used while someone is logged in to the console?

Comment: Are you sending your signature request through the api or through the web console when this happens?

Comment: I am calling a Power Form via a link from my application when this happens.  It has been acknowledged and entered as bug by my technical contact.